# string_to_array function

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm using the `sting_to_array` function in redshift `case` statement. But I get an error like -

`[0A000] ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.`

What might be the issue ?

Below is the sample code -

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN upper(url) LIKE upper('%utm_source%')
             THEN  (string_to_array(url, '&'))[1]
END as utm_source,
FROM
TEMP.table_data a2;
```

Bascially my url is of this format -

`utm_source=257509081c6f53&utm_medium=internet&utm_campaign=messenger-android&utm_term=search_keyword&utm_content=new_products`

My objective here is to extract only utm_*  values

Comment: What does the Redshift manual say about `string_to_array?

Comment: should be `split_to_array(url, '&')`?

Answer (score 0):

Array functions and operators are not supported in Redshift: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html

Instead, try using the [SPLIT_PART](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html) function:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN upper(url) LIKE upper('%utm_source%')
      THEN SPLIT_PART(url, '&', 1)
  END as utm_source
FROM
TEMP.table_data a2;
```

**Note:** The `SPLIT_PART` function starts counting from 1.